# Disable robots.txt for subdomains in nginx

Tags: nginx

I need not to serve robots.txt for any subdomain. For example, domain.com/robots.txt should be available, but blabla.domain.com/robots.txt should return 404.

I've tried it like so, but it didn't work:

```
set $subdomain FALSE;
if ($host ~* "^(([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.domain\.com)$") {
    set $subdomain TRUE;
}

location ~ "robots.txt$"{
    if ($subdomain = TRUE){
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location ~ /robots.txt
     {
       if ($host != 'domain.com') {
       return 404;
     }
}
```

Comment: This works, but why did someone downvote this answer?